# Why is my valid_triangle program from cs50 doesn't work?

Tags: c, return, boolean, cs50, function-definition

I have a problem with this code as I can't seem to find the problem? Here is the problem that I tried to solve: - Declare and write a function called valid_triangle that takes three real numbers representing the lengths of the three sides of a triangle as its arguments, and outputs either true or false, depending on whether those three lengths are capable of making a triangle.

- Following rules about triangles:

  - A triangle may only have sides with a positive length.
  - The sum of the lengths of any two sides of the triangle must be greater than the length of the third side.

```
//includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z);

int main (void)
{
   float x = get_float("x:");
   float y = get_float("y:");
   float z = get_float("z:");
   bool w = valid_triangle(x,  y,  z);
}

bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z)
{
    // only positive sides
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0)
    {
        return false;
        printf("false\n");
    }

    // sum of the lengths of any two sides of the triangle must be greater than the length of the third side.
    else if (x + y < z || x + z < y || y + z < x)
    {
        return false;
        printf("false\n");
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
        printf("True\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um, there are statements after `return` statements. May that be your problem??

Comment: You never do anything with the `w` variable.

Comment: The `return` statement returns *immediately*.

Comment: I guess the problem is that you see no prints. That has been addressed in the answer, but keep in mind that you should be more specific when asking questions. (Also, if the answer has solved your problem, make sure you accept it!)

Comment: regarding `        return false;
        printf("false\n");`  the call to `printf()` will never occur because the `return` will have already exited the function.  suggest placing the call to `printf()` before the `return` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this if statement

```
else if (x + y < z || x + z < y || y + z < x)
```

is not correct, It should look like

```
else if (x + y <= z || x + z <= y || y + z <= x)
```

And statements after return statements like in this code snippet

```
    return false;
    printf("false\n");
```

do not have an effect.  It seems you mean

```
    printf("false\n");
    return false;
```

Though the calls of `printf` should not be inside the function.

You could place only one call of printf in main like

```
bool w = valid_triangle(x,  y,  z);
printf( "%s\n", w == false ? "False" : "True" );
```

Also the last return statement within the function

```
return 0;
```

is redundant.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z)
{
    // only positive sides
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // sum of the lengths of any two sides of the triangle must be greater 
    // than the length of the third side.
    else if ( x + y <= z || x + z <= y || y + z <= x)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    float a = 4.0f, b = 5.0f, c = 6.0f;
    printf( "%.1f, %.1f, %.1f are sides of a triangle - %s\n", a, b, c,
            valid_triangle( a, b, c ) ? "true" : "false" );
            
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4.0, 5.0, 6.0 are sides of a triangle - true
```

Comment: thank you now the program works although it always returns false. Do you have an idea why it does that?

Comment: @William I appended my answer with a demonstrative program that produces the result true for valid sides of a triangle.

Comment: thank you very much although I would prefer the user to input his desired numbers

Comment: @William It is just a demonstrative program that shows that the function returns true for valid sides of a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

// This code should work as a solution for the valid_triangle program. Hope it helps

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

// first declare the function with the semi-colon at the end

```
bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z);

int main(void)
{
 // Ask users for inputs
 float a = get_float("Give me the first integer to form a triangle:  ");
 float b = get_float("Give me the second integer to form a triangle:  ");
 float c = get_float("Give me the third integer to form a triangle:  ");


// function call
bool result=valid_triangle(a, b, c);

//set condition for your boolean variable 'result'
 if (result == true)
 {
  printf("True \n");
 }
else
 {
 printf("False \n");
 }

}


//function definition, without any semi-colon at the end

bool valid_triangle(float x, float y, float z)
{
//checking if any of the sides is negative or equal to zero
if (x<=0 || y<=0 || z<=0)
{
    return false;
}

// sum of the lengths of any two sides of the triangle must be greater than the length 
//of the third side.

else if ((x+y<=z) || (x+z<=y) || (z+y<=x))
{
    return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```